# Reference ON/OFF voltage from microcontroller Raspberry Pi

Tags: voltage, raspberry-pi, gpio

I am looking for **the simplest way** to produce reference voltage **ON=1.0V** and **OFF=0.0V** from the Raspberry Pi.  I have learned that GPIO outputs are not very precise, and according to [Exploring the 3.3V Power Rail](https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/144555785379/exploring-the-33v-power-rail), 5V power rail is also not very stable.  However the document suggests that 3.3V power rail is fairly stable, so I constructed this simple circuit:

[image]

Of course I would put voltage divider at the end to get the required 1V.

The required conditions are

- at most 1% voltage drift,
- output current can be small (to be supplied to another operator amplifier).

Does this circuit make sense?  Is 3.3V power rail stable enough for this purpose?  Can you propose another, not too complicated circuit, which would be even better?

Comment: How much current do you need to be able to deliver at 1.0 V? And exactly how accurate do you need it to be? +/- 100 mV will need a very different solution from +/- 1 uV.

Comment: @ThePhoton The voltage will go directly to another op amp, so I guess no large current is needed.  The precision should be around 1%, that is the above circuit should give 3.3V +- 33mV when ON.

Comment: 1. Please edit your question to include your requirements. 2. Above circuit won't produce 3.3 V +/- 10 mV because LM358D does not provide output to the upper rail.

Comment: @ThePhoton 3.2 V +- 32mV is also fine; I am concerned about the voltage drift not about the absolute value.

Comment: LM358 with 3.3 V supply won't produce an output higher than about 1.8 V.

Comment: @ThePhoton Ups, that is a surprise for me!  How can I know the top output of LM358 depending on the supply?

Comment: Read the line on the datasheet for maximum output voltage.

Comment: @ThePhoton I am looking the datasheet, but can find that information.  Perhaps I do not look the right datasheet? http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm158-n.pdf

Comment: Page 10, figure 10.

Comment: Or in [this version](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm158a.pdf), page 5, the line "High level output voltage". I'm not sure why TI has two different versions of the datasheet accessible on their site.

Comment: Your datasheet is for LM358-N, the one I found is for LM358, and also covers LM358D.

Comment: I think the LMx58-N is probably the legacy National Semi version of the design and the "no-N" one is the TI version...but I can't be totally sure of that.

Comment: @ThePhoton Either case it is much smaller than supply voltage.  Is this characteristic of all op amps?

Comment: Pretty much. There are some op-amps that advertise "rail-to-rail output", but even those will need a few 10's of mV between the power supply and maximum output voltage, and the drop will increase with load current.

Comment: @ThePhoton What about the opposite situation?  Will op amp return true ground when V- is larger than V+?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fllk9V.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The ADR510 has an output voltage of 1.0V +/- 0.35% at room temperature.

The left circuit will supply up to about 0.9mA with source resistance < 0.3\$\Omega\$ when on, but when it is off it will only be approximately zero (depending on the GPIO low output voltage) and will have a source resistance of 2.2K, so if if any current flows into or out of it, the voltage can be far from zero.

The right hand circuit actively clamps the output to ground when GPIO is low. The source of M1 should be connected to analog ground near U2. Choose the MOSFETs to operate reliably from 3.3V Vgs and for M1 to have low enough Rds(on) with 3.3V applied to meet your needs. It's not hard to do better than the 0.3 ohms.

---

With dual P-N MOSFET array:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1wtpR.png)</sup>

Comment: I don't understand what happens when GPIO voltage is less than 1V.  Could voltage shunt be considered as a very high resistor then?

Comment: Yes, when the GPIO is close to 0V, the ADR510 will effectively disappear from the circuit. This characteristic is not well documented in the datasheet.

Comment: In that case I could modify the left circuit by using ADR520, make a voltage divider with two 1k resistors and output voltage in GPIO low situation would be only quarter of the GPIO low voltage.

Comment: Half, not quarter. You’d have 1.024 not 1.000 nominally and the tolerance and drift of the two resistors would come into play.

Comment: One question: couldn't it be possible to replace two N-channel MOSFETs M1 and M2 with one P-channel MOSFET?  If I understand the circuit right, M1 is there just to reverse logic.

Comment: No, that could short the resistor, not the shunt reference. If you put it across the reference you would need to drive it with a gate voltage a few volts below ground, which would be inconvenient.

Comment: You  could have low=on and use one resistor and a complementary dual MOSFET so the GPIO would no longer have to source the current, which would be pretty elegant.

Comment: That gave me another idea.  One could use CMOS inverter (also available as a single component) and send output to voltage shunt.  Or perhaps make non-inverter (n-channel up and p-channel down)?

Answer (score 5):

To get an output with 1.0 V +/- 1%, you will want to start with a precision voltage reference, rather than rely on an ordinary regulator. Even if the 3.3 V rail is "fairly stable", that likely means 5% or maybe 3% accuracy, not 1%.

So start with a voltage reference with better than 1% accuracy.

If it has an enable pin, you can simply use that to turn it on and off. Or if it's a shunt reference, you can cut off its power supply to drop its output to 0 V.

If you can't find a 1.00 V fixed-output reference (I don't know of any, off the top of my head) you'll need to either use an adjustable reference, in which case the accuracy depends on the resistors you use to trim the output voltage; or divide-and-buffer the output of a higher-voltage reference, which again introduces error contributions from resistors. Luckily 0.1% resistors are not particularly expensive.